# Highest Weight vectors in tensor product of irreducible

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Suppose $V_\lambda$ and $V_\mu$ are two irreducible Lie Algebra representations with highest weight vectors $v_\lambda$ and $v_\mu$, respectively. I can decompose the tensor product $V_\lambda \otimes V_\mu = \oplus V_{\nu}^{m_\nu}$ and I would like to know a systematic way to figure out the highest weight vectors of each $V_\nu$ in terms of the highest weight vectors $v_\lambda$ and $v_\mu$.

For a simplest example that I am working with for intuition, I have $V_\lambda = V_\mu = \mathfrak{sl}_n$, the adjoint representation. For simplicity of notation let $n= 6$, then I have that $[1 \ 0 \ 0\  0\ 1] \otimes [1 \ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1] = [2\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 2] \oplus [2\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0] \oplus [ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 2] \oplus [0\ 1\ 0\ 1\ 0] \oplus 2[ 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1] \oplus [ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0]$.

I know that $v_\lambda \otimes v_\mu= v_{\lambda + \mu}$, where $v_\lambda = E_1^n$ and $v_\mu = F_1^n$, would give me the highest weight vector of $[2\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 2]$, but I am unsure how to obtain highest weight vectors of the other representations in the decomposition in a systematic fashion.

I understand that this problem in full generality is quite difficult, but I'd appreciate any guidance or perhaps a reference where I can understand this. Please let me know if anything requires further clarification. Thank you for your time!

Comment: So to start we can find the weight vectors (forgetting about "highest for a second") as the simple tensors consisting of two weight vectors. Now, to find those which are highest weight, we need to understand how the upper triangular part acts on these. Probably the easiest way to understand this is to obtain the weight vectors by acting with lower triangular matrices in the first place, and use that to check if the upper triangular matrices kill the simple tensor.

Comment: thank you for explaining!